# One-way communication with child iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, sandbox

I want to pass parameters to a child iframe that hosts third party code. But the third party code should not be allowed to interact with the parent. Is that possible?

I have played with sandbox settings, it seems that every time I add a restriction it applies both ways.

The parameters could be strings or complex objects, including functions.

I am using Reactjs.